# Multi Select Drop Down Highlighted in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, dropdown

**JSP:**

```
<s:form action="product">

<s:select label="Select Data"
    cssStyle="width:150; height:73"
    size="6"
    multiple="true"
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="All"
    list="#{'1':'Data1', '2':'Data2', '3':'Data3', '4':'Data4' }"
    name="dataValue"
    value="%{2,3}" />
<s:submit value="save"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

**Action:**

```
public class Product {
private String dataValue;
//getter setter
.......
public String execute(){  
                return "success";  
    }

}
```

**Problem:**
at a time one field is selected only for example I passed value 2,3 then only `Data3` is selected  but i wants `Data2` and `Data3` selected.

Comment: Type mismatch. You have different types in list and in value.

Answer (score 1):

To pre-select multiple values you need to use list or array for the action property in the `value` attribute.

'1', '2',... are character type values, so you return a character list

```
public List<Character> getDataValue(){
  return dataValue;
}

<s:select label="Select Data"
    cssStyle="width:150; height:73"
    size="6"
    multiple="true"
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="All"
    list="#{'1':'Data1', '2':'Data2', '3':'Data3', '4':'Data4' }"
    name="dataValue"
    value="%{dataValue}" />
```

Comment: working fine but only problem is for  All , value comes [-] and its not selecting. i also tried headerKey= "0"  not working